# Speed up selection by a combination of two columns — Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Currently, I am trying to select rows from a large dataframe (1.5 million rows), called active, by a combination of two columns from another dataframe, called passive, which has about 30,000 rows. If a combination of two columns in the active table matches the combination of two columns in the passive table, I select the row from the active table.

```
Here is the code:
active.loc[(active['userid']+active['orgcity']).isin(passive.userid+passive.city)]
```

However, this process is taking a long time. I think it should already be an improvement over iteration or pd.apply. Are there any other ways to speed this up?

Comment: For perspective, what do you consider "a long time"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can put each row entry [passive.userid, passive.city] in a set. That way your "in B" check becomes an O(1) lookup instead of an O(n) and this gives you a 30,000x speedup.
2. Then use the apply() function in pandas to vectorize the lookup. Here's an example of apply(). 
   [image]

You can find more details [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

Comment: Thanks, putting it into a set really sped things up a ton! My problem is now solved, but I'm just curious, what do you mean by a mapper function in the second part?

Comment: Edited answer to be more specific about mapping operation.